# Determine if script is running within an RStudio notebook

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

In my [htmlTable](https://github.com/gforge/htmlTable) package I've been using `base::interactive` in order to determine if output should be outputted as a string or into a browser window (here's the [code](https://github.com/gforge/htmlTable/blob/1.7/R/htmlTable.R#L954-L1023)). Unfortunately `interactive()` returns `TRUE` when running within an [RStudio notebook](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html), what is the equivalent way of determining the execution environment within a notebook?

I've tried `ls()` and `search()` but they look identical regardless of the environment. I also have the `knit_print.htmlTable` S3 function that is called by [default for knitr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_print.html#for-package-authors) documents but it doesn't seem to detect it properly in the notebook environment.

Comment: See if testing that `knitr::opts_current$get('results')` is not `NULL`. It's set in a notebook or R Markdown context but not in a plain script context (at least on my systems).

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work when running just a chunk. Ideally I would like something official for package maintainers from RStudio but I haven't been able to find anything more useful.

Comment: Hrm. I ran it in just a chunk and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'm sitting on a Windows computer and the output is null :-/

Comment: methinks it's time to head over to rstudio support forums and post an issue and feature request. I think a full on proper variable in some accessible environment (or `knitr` / `rstudioapi` pkg function call) shld be able to return more info.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - wrote a comment on the main page requesting a *for package maintainers* instructions.

Comment: On Windows, I now see knitr::opts_current$get('results') getting set both during knitting and in RNotebooks.  Unfortunately, it hangs around after execution, so is present if I then start doing work in the R console.

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution that I've found so far is to implement a context detector using the RStudio API:

```
prIsNotebook <- function() {
  if (!rstudioapi::isAvailable()) {
    return(FALSE)
  }

  ctxt <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()
  if (grepl("\\.Rmd$", ctxt$path)) {
    return(TRUE)
  }

  # Look for html_notebook within the header if the file hasn't been saved
  contents <- ctxt$contents
  header <- grep("^---$", contents)
  if (length(header) == 2) {
    return(any(grepl("html_notebook$",
                     contents[min(header) : max(header)])))
  }

  return(FALSE)
}
```

I won't check this as the answer since this more of a hack than a true solution.

Comment: I have RNotebooks that I also sometimes knit to Word or PDF, and even occasionally HTML - I therefore have ALL of these as output formats in my YAML header section :-(